# C# Regex not returning

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a practice problem which gives me a much longer set of strings.  I need to pull the strings out of the quotation marks (wh

```
// names is a string[] composed of names like these: "BOB", "JOE", "FRANK", etc... 
// (the ""s are part of the string, not string designations). I suppose that makes them "\"Bob\"", etc...

foreach(string name in names)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("/\"(.+)\"/");
    Match match = regex.Match(name);
    Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
    if (match.Success) 
    {
            Console.WriteLine("string: {0} and match value: {1}", name, match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

I'm not logging out anything.  I've tried referencing `.Value` several ways, but I can't log normal strings either so I'm not getting any matches off of my Regex.  I've followed a couple of examples too.

Regex101 tells me that I should be matching fine, so I've got to have some error in my C# implementation.  But I can't figure it out.  I just need someone to set me straight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the forward slashes in your regex. They are used to indicate the start and end of a regular expression in some languages or formats, which is not needed when creating one through the `Regex` class.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"(.+)\"");
```

Result:

> "BOB"
>
> string: "BOB" and match value: BOB